# UWP one handed mode

Tags: uwp

I have my UWP application and I wan't to open it using the handed mode programmatically.

Is it possible to open two applications using the "one handed mode" in a windows 10 device programmatically ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to open two applications using the "one handed mode" in a windows 10 device programmatically?

No, there is no API can enable "one-handed mode" programmatically for now.

The "one-handed mode" is used to simplify the handling of the Windows 10 Mobile device with a single hand. We can only enable one-handed mode by tapping and holding the ***Windows*** button. And things go back to normal if we tap the black part of the screen, don't touch anything for a few seconds, or tap and hold the ***Windows*** button again.

And even there is such API, we still can't open two applications using this mode.

In one-handed mode, the screen will slide down showing only the top half of it. The top of the screen becomes black and it is essentially not used to show any information. The idea is to use only the bottom half of the screen and have everything available for easy reach with user's thumb.

So there will always be only one application in one-handed mode.